# Como retornar o valor de um select para um ng-repeat no angular

Tags: angularjs

Pessoal tenho um select que tem 3 opções 1,2 e 4, preciso que ao escolher um desses números uma div se repita 1, 2 ou 4 vezes de acordo com o select escolhido, como faço isso com Angular?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um exemplo bem simples seria fazer um `range` dos números criando um `filter` para essa finalidade e conforme as escolhas do `select`, alterar uma variável do `$scope` para carregar as `div`, `exemplo`:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', [])
app.filter('range', function() {
  return function(input, total) {
    total = parseInt(total);
    for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
      input.push(i);
    }
    return input;
  };
});
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.line = 0;
});
```

```css
.divC {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <select ng-model="line">
  <option value="0">Inicial</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

  <div>
    <div class="divC" ng-repeat="n in [] | range:line">
      {{$index}}
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Um outra forma, criando um [Array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp):

```js
var app = angular.module('app', [])
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.line = 0;
  $scope.lines = function(value) {    
    return new Array(parseInt(value));       
  };  
});
```

```css
.divC {
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--Pessoal tenho um select que tem 3 opções 1,2 e 4, preciso que ao escolher um desses números uma div se repita 1, 2 ou 4 vezes de acordo com o select escolhido, como faço isso com Angular?-->
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <select ng-model="line">
  <option value="0">Inicial</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<div>
    <div class="divC" ng-repeat="n in lines(line) track by $index">
      {{$index}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [AngularJS ng-repeat Directive](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-repeat.asp)
- [Javascript - Array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)
- [Way to ng-repeat defined number of times instead of repeating over array? - SO<sup>EN</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824853/way-to-ng-repeat-defined-number-of-times-instead-of-repeating-over-array)

Comment: Legal brother, bem isso que precisava, agradeço!